# Windows 7 PC claims "not connected to network" even though it is

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, windows-networking

I'm having trouble accessing my LAN from my connected computer. I have mapped drives on the LAN that my computer can access, and it shows a wireless connection to the correct wireless LAN. However, when I click on the "Network" icon in My Computer, I get a popup message that tells me I am not connected to a network.

Upon clicking on the popup message in order to connect to a network, it invokes the Wireless Network chooser - which clearly shows that I AM connected to the wireless network. So I can't really do anything further.

In the notifications bar, the bireless network icon shows a red X on it. I have tried disabling and re-enabling the adaptor and that has yielded no joy thus far.

Appreciate any additional troubleshooting steps, particularly those that don't begin with "Reinstall Windows..."

Comment: Have you double checked those directories are set to be shared?

Comment: Has this connection worked properly in the past? What type of connection does Windows 7 see you are connected to? If it it set to `public`, you will have limited access to network resources.

Comment: From the described red X through your Wireless Network Icon, you may have a Laptop that uses a Manual switch, or button that will enable, or disable your Wireless LAN, check to see if you have one, and re-enable your Wi-Fi.

Comment: Hi @Michael - not sure whether you read my post properly. I AM currently connected to the LAN via WiFi, so clearly my WiFi switch is ON. I'm just not connected "to the network", whatever that means. BTW I CAN access mapped drives, AND the internet.